# Downloading OpenNEX Datasets

Tags: references, docker

Does anybody have a tutorial on how to download NASA NEX-GDDP downscaled GCMs dataset from http://opennex.planetos.com/ website as csv?

I´m not familiar with the use of Docker, containers, etc.

Comment: Link is broken.  In any event, if this is open data then any questions about downloading it may be better asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: aws cli is a simple way https://registry.opendata.aws/nasanex/ No AWS account required.